# Can't render chart, data from api

Tags: api, vue-chartjs

I get data from api. i can show chartdata but it not render a chart.
my code:

```
<script>
import { Pie, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
mixins: [mixins.reactiveData],
extends: Pie,
data() {
return {
  chartdata: ''
 }
},
mounted () {
this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options)
},

created() {
axios.get("http://localhost:3000/chart1")
.then(response => {
  const responseData = response.data
  
  this.chartdata = {
    labels: responseData.map(item => item.lb),
    datasets: 
      [
          {
            label: 'hrlo',
            backgroundColor: ['purple','#b2b2b2'],
            data: responseData.map(item => item.dt)
          }
      ]
  } 
 })
  .catch( e => {
    this.errors.push(e)
  })

 },  
}
</script>
```

api: [
{
"lb": "Android",
"dt": 80
},
{
"lb": "IOS",
"dt": 20
}
]

i'm sorry because of my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Can you also include any error messages? I am suspecting that the wrong data structure of "chartdata" is causing an error before even retrieving the data to display, i.e. "chartdata" needs to be

```
chartdata: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: []
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i don't think so. because i can show chartdata. my code :
  <div v-for="item in chartdata" v-bind:key="item">
        {{ item }}
  </div>
and result: 
[ "Android", "IOS" ]
[ { "label": "hrlo", "backgroundColor": [ "purple", "#b2b2b2" ], "data": [ 80, 20 ] } ]
but i can't render this chartdata

Comment: @HiếuLêVăn Thank you for the clarification. Is there any error messages the module is returning?

Comment: no hav error. t can solve. i need re-render after get data @@